# Creating counter at group by level in pandas Dataframe, optimization

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, group-by, counter

I have a dataset like this:

```
user_id  communication_type  
7         Newsletter
7         Newsletter
7         Newsletter
7         Newsletter
7         Conference
7    Upcoming Events
7    Upcoming Events
7    Upcoming Events
7         Conference
7         Conference
7            Webinar
7          Hackathon
```

Desired Output:

```
user_id  communication_type    sent_past
7         Newsletter            0
7         Newsletter            1
7         Newsletter            2
7         Newsletter            3
7         Conference            0
7    Upcoming Events            0 
7    Upcoming Events            1
7    Upcoming Events            2  
7         Conference            1
7         Conference            2 
7            Webinar            0
7          Hackathon            0
```

Basically get a counter at each level of communication_type for a particular user_id.

The solutions which is working for me:

```
train['sent_past'] = train.groupby(['user_id','communication_type']).apply(lambda x: x.reset_index()).index.get_level_values(1)
```

But it's very slow on ~1m rows. How can I optimize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).

```
df['sent_past'] = df.groupby('communication_type').cumcount()

print(df)

    user_id communication_type  sent_past
0         7         Newsletter          0
1         7         Newsletter          1
2         7         Newsletter          2
3         7         Newsletter          3
4         7         Conference          0
5         7    Upcoming Events          0
6         7    Upcoming Events          1
7         7    Upcoming Events          2
8         7         Conference          1
9         7         Conference          2
10        7            Webinar          0
11        7          Hackathon          0
```

Or for combinations of `user_id` and `communication_type` use:

```
df['sent_past'] = df.groupby(['user_id', 'communication_type']).cumcount()
```

Comment: aah, i was thinking what to count for cumcount, in groupby. but just calling the function works. interesting